# Android StrictMode issue with Huawei Mate 9 Nougat

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-espresso, android-strictmode

I've got an Android Instrumented test where I try to start my application and perform the following operations:

```
open class MyApplication : Application() {

...

  override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()

    initialiseLogging()
    initialiseStrictMode()
    initialiseDependencyGraph()
  }

  private fun initialiseDependencyGraph() {
    applicationComponent = createApplicationComponent()
    applicationComponent.inject(this)
  }

...

  private fun initialiseStrictMode() {
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
      .detectDiskReads()
      .detectDiskWrites()
      .detectNetwork()
      .penaltyDeath()
      .build())
  }
}
```

**All tests pass on most devices** when I run them on Firebase, except on **Huawei Mate 9 with Nougat (Android 7.0 with API 24)**. When I run my tests against this device I get the following error:

```
02-19 15:25:13.822: E/InstrumentationResultPrinter(10431): Failed to mark test No Tests as finished after process crash
02-19 15:25:13.822: E/MonitoringInstr(10431): Exception encountered by: au.com.dius.powersensor.platform.TestApp@2b58cb5. Dumping thread state to outputs and pining for the fjords.
02-19 15:25:13.822: E/MonitoringInstr(10431): android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeViolation: policy=262151 violation=2
02-19 15:25:13.822: E/MonitoringInstr(10431):   at android.os.StrictMode.executeDeathPenalty(StrictMode.java:1556)
02-19 15:25:13.822: E/MonitoringInstr(10431):   at android.os.StrictMode.-wrap3(StrictMode.java)
02-19 15:25:13.822: E/MonitoringInstr(10431):   at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.handleViolation(StrictMode.java:1549)
02-19 15:25:13.822: E/MonitoringInstr(10431):   at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.handleViolationWithTimingAttempt(StrictMode.java:1367)
02-19 15:25:13.822: E/MonitoringInstr(10431):   at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.startHandlingViolationException(StrictMode.java:1337)
02-19 15:25:13.822: E/MonitoringInstr(10431):   at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onReadFromDisk(StrictMode.java:1306)
02-19 15:25:13.822: E/MonitoringInstr(10431):   at java.io.UnixFileSystem.checkAccess(UnixFileSystem.java:249)
02-19 15:25:13.822: E/MonitoringInstr(10431):   at java.io.File.exists(File.java:780)
02-19 15:25:13.822: E/MonitoringInstr(10431):   at android.graphics.Typeface.initHwFontConfig(Typeface.java:295)
02-19 15:25:13.822: E/MonitoringInstr(10431):   at android.graphics.Typeface.updateFont(Typeface.java:361)
02-19 15:25:13.822: E/MonitoringInstr(10431):   at android.graphics.Typeface.loadSystemFonts(Typeface.java:444)
02-19 15:25:13.822: E/MonitoringInstr(10431):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5671)
02-19 15:25:13.822: E/MonitoringInstr(10431):   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
02-19 15:25:13.822: E/MonitoringInstr(10431):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1637)
02-19 15:25:13.822: E/MonitoringInstr(10431):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-19 15:25:13.822: E/MonitoringInstr(10431):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
02-19 15:25:13.822: E/MonitoringInstr(10431):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6524)
02-19 15:25:13.822: E/MonitoringInstr(10431):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-19 15:25:13.822: E/MonitoringInstr(10431):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:941)
02-19 15:25:13.822: E/MonitoringInstr(10431):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:831)
```

It seems clear to me that `StricMode` has caught a bizarre error where the `ActivityThread` tries to initialise the font system by loading them from the disk using the main thread.

There's nothing online providing a solution to this bug and it seems odd that my tests fail only for this specific device.

Anyone has any ideas about how to solve this issue or what might be causing it?

Comment: It looks like this device needs to read a file to load system fonts.  Remove detectDiskReads from your strict mode policy.

Comment: Around these error logcat, there may be some helpful warning or info logcat.